# Resolution of image from camera to Imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, pixel

I want to take a picture and add image to the activity. I was having a weird pixelation and at first i thought that it was something with the blob I used, but it seems like it has to do with the image after capture from camera.

I activate the camera to take a picture

```
Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

Then I want to set image at the imageview.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            int width = photo.getWidth();
            int height = photo.getHeight();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Width:"+width+" / Height:"+height,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Screen.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

    }
```

After I take the image and there is a preview to verify that I want the image the picture gets pixelated and the resolution of the bitmap I get is 150x205 and I don't know what have I done wrong.

I uploaded a small video to see the actual resolution http://youtu.be/s5Cu3QYSDto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android the default data which you get from camera is low resolution thumbnail image.

So before you call CameraIntent create a file and uri based on that filepath as shown here.

```
filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/testfile.jpg";
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));

// start default camera
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                imageUri);
startActivityForResult (cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Now, you have the filepath you can use it in onAcityvityResult method as following,you can also get the bitmap from the uri.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your way but when I take the photo and click on the verify icon It stops there. And there is no generated file for that when I tried to find with file explorer.
--edit
I also tried it on api19 and it didn't work (i'm on lollipop)